# Extra Pages Showing in SiteCat

Tags: ios, adobe-analytics

I'm implementing a new tag into our iOS app using Adobe Analytics. There's just one issue -- when I go to correlate the tag based off page names, I get way more pages than I do "Visits" to the tag. For example, if I correlate a tag that got 3 visits, it may have 6-8 different pages listed for it.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why more pages may report than times the tag fired? I've set a breakpoint on the place where the tag fires and can't for the life of me get it to fire when it's not supposed to, which makes sense since I don't see it firing more than it should but see more pages than I should.

I'm at a bit of a loss -- I can provide more details if needed but I've never seen this before so I'm not sure what details I could provide that may help. I've implemented tags with no issues in the past, so any help at all is appreciated!

Edit: I've added the code below, let me know if you see anything weird in how I track the list variable:

```
+ (void)trackListNumber:(NSUInteger)listNumber withValue:(NSString *)list3Value withEventName:(NSString *)eventName pageName:(NSString *)pageName andContextData:(NSDictionary *)contextData {

    [self setCachedPageName:pageName];

    ADMS_Measurement *measure = [ADMS_Measurement sharedInstance];
    [measure clearVars];
    if(listNumber && [NSString isValidString:list3Value]){
        [measure setListVar:listNumber toValue:list3Value];
    }

    NSDictionary *eventContextData;
    if (contextData) {
        NSMutableDictionary *mutableContextData = [[self prepareContextDataForTagging] mutableCopy];
        [mutableContextData addEntriesFromDictionary:contextData];
        eventContextData = [mutableContextData copy];
    } else {
        eventContextData = contextData;
    }

    if (eventName) measure.events = eventName;
    measure.appState = (pageName) ? pageName : kAppStatePageNameNull;
    [measure trackWithContextData:eventContextData];
}
```

Comment: A visit and a page view are two different scopes.  A page view is hit scope and will include what happened for the single hit (request) to Adobe. A visit is (kind of) like a session, so many things can happen during the course of a visit.  For example, a visitor can, during the course of a visit, view 10 pages on your site. So you will see 10 pages listed for that visit.

Comment: Interesting, changing my metric to Page Views did solve the issue. I wonder how this is happening now, for the most part we call `clearVars` before tracking, so shouldn't that reset the "session" associated with each persistent variable?

Comment: No. `clearVars` wipes AA vars on a code level, that's it.  Activities during visits are tied together on Adobe's servers, based on the visitor id cookie vs. activity (e.g. if more than 30 minutes pass between 2 requests to Adobe, Adobe will count it as a new session (visit) started)